# remove background colour from jquery tabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-tabs

I would like to remove the background grey colour of the container holding the 2 tabs. So only the tabs are coloured. Ive removed all the CSS but not joy. It must be coming from the the JQuery `.tabs()`, can anyone advise how I can remove this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".shoptab").tabs();
});
```

```css
#list ul {
     border-radius: 0;
     background: none;
     border: 0;
     border-bottom: 1px solid #cbcdcd;
   }
   #list ul li {
     border-radius: 0;
   }
   #list {
     border: 0;
   }
   .ui-state-default,
   .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default,
   .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
     border-color: #e4e4e4;
     background: #f2f2f2;
     color: #cbcbcb;
   }
   .ui-state-default {
     color: #e7e7e7;
   }
   .ui-state-active,
   .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
   .ui-widget-header .ui-state-active {
     border-color: #cbcdcd;
     background: #fff;
     color: #333333;
   }
   .ui-state-hover,
   .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
   .ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover {
     border: 1px solid #cbcdcd;
   }
   .ui-state-selected ui-state-hover,
   #ui-state-active ui-state-hover {
     background: #fff:
   }
   .ui-state-default a,
   .ui-state-default a:link,
   .ui-state-default a:visited {
     color: #a9a9a9;
   }
   .ui-state-hover a,
   .ui-state-hover a:hover {
     color: #333333;
   }
   .ui-state-active a,
   .ui-state-active a:link,
   .ui-state-active a:visited {
     color: #333333;
   }
   #list li ul li {
     margin-left: 10px;
     font-size: 11px;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
   }
   #list li ul li a {
     padding: 4px 7px 4px 7px;
   }
   #list li ul {
     margin: 0;
   }
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="loc-list">
  <div class="shoptab">
    <h2>Shop 1</h2>

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">Address</a>

      </li>
      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Opening hours</a>

      </li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
      <p>Tab 1 content</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
      <p>Tab 2 content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.ui-widget-header` background

Comment: Please include your code in the question. If JSFiddle goes down (as it frequently does) your question becomes impossible to answer. That is why the code restriction, which you have gotten around, exists.

Comment: fairly trivial to figure this out using browser dev tools css inspectors

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove style border and background for element `.ui-widget-header`

```
.ui-widget-header {
   border: 0px;
   background: none;
}
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rn5dwtdq/)**

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for. I used white but you can add whatever color you like.

```
.ui-widegt-header a{
width: 100%
background-color: none;
}
```